# SVG - Animate doesn't work with class selector

Tags: animation, svg

I try to animate "stroke-dashoffset" of several lines, I try to use xlink:".class" but it doesn't work. 
The animation only works with xlink:"#id"
Is it normal ?

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Calque_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" enable-background="new 0 0 200 200" xml:space="preserve">
<g clip-path="url(#SVGID_2_)">
    <line id="LIGNE" class="LI"  stroke="#38519F"  x1="56.5" y1="127" x2="56.5" y2="77"  stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="150 150" stroke-dashoffset="200"/>
    <line class="LI"  stroke="#38519F"  x1="59.5" y1="129" x2="59.5" y2="78"  stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="150 150" stroke-dashoffset="200"/>
    <line class="LI"  stroke="#38519F"  x1="62.5" y1="131" x2="62.5" y2="80"  stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="150 150" stroke-dashoffset="200"/>
    <line class="LI"  stroke="#38519F"  x1="65.5" y1="132" x2="65.5" y2="82"  stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="150 150" stroke-dashoffset="200"/>
    <line class="LI"  stroke="#38519F"  x1="68.5" y1="134" x2="68.5" y2="83"  stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="150 150" stroke-dashoffset="200"/>
    <line class="LI"  stroke="#38519F"  x1="71.5" y1="136" x2="71.5" y2="85"  stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="150 150" stroke-dashoffset="200"/>
    <line class="LI"  stroke="#38519F"  x1="74.5" y1="138" x2="74.5" y2="87"  stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="150 150" stroke-dashoffset="200"/>
    <line class="LI"  stroke="#38519F"  x1="77.5" y1="139" x2="77.5" y2="89"  stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="150 150" stroke-dashoffset="200"/>
    <line class="LI"  stroke="#38519F"  x1="80.5" y1="141" x2="80.5" y2="90"  stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="150 150" stroke-dashoffset="200"/>
    <line class="LI"  stroke="#38519F"  x1="83.5" y1="143" x2="83.5" y2="92"  stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="150 150" stroke-dashoffset="200"/>
    <line class="LI"  stroke="#38519F"  x1="86.5" y1="144" x2="86.5" y2="94"  stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="150 150" stroke-dashoffset="200"/>
    <line class="LI"  stroke="#38519F"  x1="89.5" y1="146" x2="89.5" y2="95"  stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="150 150" stroke-dashoffset="200"/>
    <line class="LI"  stroke="#38519F"  x1="92.5" y1="148" x2="92.5" y2="97"  stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="150 150" stroke-dashoffset="200"/>
    <line class="LI"  stroke="#38519F"  x1="95.5" y1="150" x2="95.5" y2="99"  stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="150 150" stroke-dashoffset="200"/>
    <line class="LI"  stroke="#38519F"  x1="98.5" y1="151" x2="98.5" y2="101" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="150 150" stroke-dashoffset="200"/>
    <animate  xlink:href=".LI"  attributeType="xml" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="200" to="0"  dur="0.5s" fill="freeze" />
</g></svg>
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/pierrearfarf/7L1kx6t6/1/

Thx for reading.

Comment: That's normal. Thats SMIL for you. w3c are working on a new specification http://w3c.github.io/web-animations/ but no UA implements enough of that specification to do what you want yet.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. I'm confused, should I use CSS or Jquery, or in this case just add one <animate> tag per line in svg ? What's the more efficient ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use css animations instead, something like this:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes dashanim {
    from { stroke-dashoffset: 200; }
    to { stroke-dashoffset: 0 }
}
@-ms-keyframes dashanim {
    from { stroke-dashoffset: 200; }
    to { stroke-dashoffset: 0 }
}
@keyframes dashanim {
    from { stroke-dashoffset: 200; }
    to { stroke-dashoffset: 0 }
}
.LI {
    -webkit-animation-name: dashanim;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    
    -ms-animation-name: dashanim;
    -ms-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    
    animation-name: dashanim;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Calque_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" enable-background="new 0 0 200 200" xml:space="preserve">
 <g clip-path="url(#SVGID_2_)">
  <line id="LIGNE" class="LI" fill="none" stroke="#38519F" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="56.5" y1="127" x2="56.5" y2="77"  stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="150 150" stroke-dashoffset="200"/>
  <line class="LI" fill="none" stroke="#38519F" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="59.5" y1="129" x2="59.5" y2="78"  stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="150 150" stroke-dashoffset="200"/>
  <line class="LI" fill="none" stroke="#38519F" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="62.5" y1="131" x2="62.5" y2="80"  stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="150 150" stroke-dashoffset="200"/>
  <line class="LI" fill="none" stroke="#38519F" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="65.5" y1="132" x2="65.5" y2="82"  stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="150 150" stroke-dashoffset="200"/>
  <line class="LI" fill="none" stroke="#38519F" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="68.5" y1="134" x2="68.5" y2="83"  stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="150 150" stroke-dashoffset="200"/>
  <line class="LI" fill="none" stroke="#38519F" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="71.5" y1="136" x2="71.5" y2="85"  stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="150 150" stroke-dashoffset="200"/>
  <line class="LI" fill="none" stroke="#38519F" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="74.5" y1="138" x2="74.5" y2="87"  stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="150 150" stroke-dashoffset="200"/>
  <line class="LI" fill="none" stroke="#38519F" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="77.5" y1="139" x2="77.5" y2="89"  stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="150 150" stroke-dashoffset="200"/>
  <line class="LI" fill="none" stroke="#38519F" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="80.5" y1="141" x2="80.5" y2="90"  stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="150 150" stroke-dashoffset="200"/>
  <line class="LI" fill="none" stroke="#38519F" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="83.5" y1="143" x2="83.5" y2="92"  stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="150 150" stroke-dashoffset="200"/>
  <line class="LI" fill="none" stroke="#38519F" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="86.5" y1="144" x2="86.5" y2="94"  stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="150 150" stroke-dashoffset="200"/>
  <line class="LI" fill="none" stroke="#38519F" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="89.5" y1="146" x2="89.5" y2="95"  stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="150 150" stroke-dashoffset="200"/>
  <line class="LI" fill="none" stroke="#38519F" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="92.5" y1="148" x2="92.5" y2="97"  stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="150 150" stroke-dashoffset="200"/>
  <line class="LI" fill="none" stroke="#38519F" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="95.5" y1="150" x2="95.5" y2="99"  stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="150 150" stroke-dashoffset="200"/>
  <line class="LI" fill="none" stroke="#38519F" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="98.5" y1="151" x2="98.5" y2="101" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="150 150" stroke-dashoffset="200"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```